# Getting implicit val from the companion object

Tags: scala, implicit, spray

I'm playing with Scala Spray. I enjoy working with it but can't figure out one thing.

This code compiles fine:

```
import spray.http.MediaTypes._
import spray.routing.HttpService
import spray.json.{DefaultJsonProtocol, _}
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._

trait StatusService extends HttpService {

  case class StatusResponse(status: String)

  object StatusResponseProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val statusResponse = jsonFormat1(StatusResponse)
  }

  import StatusResponseProtocol._

  val statusRoute =
    path("status") {
      get {
        respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
          complete {
            StatusResponse("OK")
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't compile (can't find json serializer) when I move case class & protocol to the companion object.

```
trait StatusService extends HttpService {

  import StatusResponseProtocol._

  val statusRoute =
    path("status") {
      get {
        respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
          complete {
            StatusResponse("OK")
          }
        }
      }
    }
}

object StatusService {

  case class StatusResponse(status: String)

  object StatusResponseProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val statusResponse = jsonFormat1(StatusResponse)
  }
}
```

I do not understand why..

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be in your import statement. If you import from a companion object, it should be done like this:

```
trait StatusService extends HttpService {

  import StatusService.StatusResponseProtocol._
```

The rest of the code doesn't have to be changed.

Comment: can you add the whole output from the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've had pretty much the same problem. Try replacing:

```
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._
```

with

```
import spray.json._
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed today (in another context, not Spray) that providing a type for the `implicit val` in a companion object made it visible.

So, I'm thinking whether this would make it work in your case:

```
implicit val statusResponse: RootJsonFormat[StatusResponse] = jsonFormat1(StatusResponse)
```

Note: I'm not sure of the type I added - it may not be what `jsonFormat1` returns. Also, the Spray.json documentation does not use types. Anyways, if someone has the time to try this out, I'd be interested to know..

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for sharing!